# HelpAndroid map marker change start and end color, put different details and add polylines

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there a way I can change the icon of start and end of marker like blue for start and red for end, add different details and add connecting polyline?

Button:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list_location.size(); i++) {
                    createMarker(list_location.get(i).getLatitude(), list_location.get(i).getLongitude());
                }
            }
            });
```

Marker:

```
private void createMarker(String latitude, String longitude) {
    // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, Longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title("title")
            .snippet("snippet")
            .icon(icon));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy but seems you haven't tried much

you can use index to find first and last points
and draw different color based on position

i.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_location.size(); i++) {
    createMarker(i, list_location.get(i).getLatitude(),list_location.get(i).getLongitude());
}
```

and in your `createMarker()` method

```
private void createMarker(int index, String latitude, String longitude) {
    // Adding the taped point to the ArrayList
if (index == 0)
color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.COLOR_THAT_SUITS;
else if (index == list_location.size()-1)
color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.COLOR_THAT_SUITS;

//set this color to your marker
.....
.....
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color)));
```

}

Comment: Hi, thank you for that answer. I was expecting of polyline. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Michael Shrestha, can you pls. enlighten me with my code? Thanks.